# Implications of vectors in the span of eigenvectors of operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, operator-theory

Given an operator $\hat{A}$ and a vector $|v \rangle$ (I am using bra-ket notation), why does it follow that if we assume that $| v \rangle$ is not in the span of eigenvectors of $\hat{A}$ then $$\langle v | \hat{A} | v \rangle = 0?$$

Further, if we know that $\hat{A} = \sum_{n} c_n |w_n \rangle \langle w_n|$ (not diagonalized, hence $| w_n \rangle$ are not the eigenstates of $\hat{A}$) and $|v \rangle$ is not in the linear span of $\{ |w \rangle_n \}_n$ then why does it follow that $| w \rangle_n$ must be in the span of eigenvectors of $\hat{A}$?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Is this in a finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: @Demophilus Yes it is, sorry forgot to include that.

Comment: Still doesn't seem true, suppose we have $A = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{matrix} \right)$. Then $\left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{matrix} \right)$ is its only eigenvector (aside from some factor) but $v=\left( \begin{matrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)$ also doesn't satisfy $v^T A v = 0$.

Comment: @Demophilus Thanks for your response. I see your point, let me think about that for a bit. What about the second query, do you have any idea how to show this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second question. Are $w_n$ a base of the space? Orthonormal? Or just any collection of vectors? Moreover what does $v$ have to do with your second question?

Comment: @Demophilus $|w_n \rangle$ is just a set of vectors which defines $\hat{A}$, not necessarily orthogonal. This is part of a proof which uses the idea that if $v$ is not in the span of eigenstates of $\hat{A}$ then that implies that it is not in the span of $\{ | w_n \rangle \}_n$ and hence that implies that each $|w_n \rangle$ is in the linear span of eigenstates of $\hat{A}$, I can't see how the last part follows...